# Detect circle From drawing image (PYTHON -OPENCV )

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I want to detect the small circles that exist inside the line, I used this code below but it does not detect the right points.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
image = cv2.imread("image_33(1).png",0)  # Load in grayscale
# Apply thresholding to convert to binary image
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Apply edge detection
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

circle_params = dict(
    dp=1,      # Resolution of inverse accumulator 1
    minDist=180,  # Minimum distance between centers of circles 
    param1=150,  # Specific parameter of circle detection method 
    param2=15, # Specific parameter of circle detection method 
    minRadius=4,  # Minimum radius of circles to detect 
    maxRadius= 10 # Maximum radius of circles to detect 7
)


# Appliquer la détection de cercles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, **circle_params)

# Dessiner les contours et les cercles détectés sur l'image
image_with_contours = cv2.drawContours(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
image_with_circles = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype(int)
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(image_with_circles, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)
# Afficher les résultats
cv2.imwrite("detect_Circles(5).jpg", image_with_circles)
```

> j'ai utilisé le code de houghcircle mais il a pu détecté les petits cercles

> I used the hough circle code but it was not able to detect the small circles

*(PS: This translated version of above sentence was translated using google translate. Main idea may vary.)*

Comment: Use inverted threshold followd by an erode that removes the thin black lines. Afterwards, only your circles/dots should be there as white blobs.

Comment: posting code with French comments on an English forum will not help much

Comment: those small "circles" are black dots. blob detector should pick them up. morphology sounds like a good idea too since everything else (apart from the "rails"/walls) is less solid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.